# How to generate Visual Studio Solutions for Multi-targetting via CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, native

Visual Studio, as of VS2010, supports the concept of [multi-targetting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx), where a solution can be configured for, and built with, the compiler, libraries and includes of preceding Visual Studio versions. For example, the 2010 IDE can be used to build with the v90 (2008) toolset; in 2012 IDE can be used to build with v90, v100, v110 and v110_xp toolchains, and so on.

The question is this; how to configure a CMake build system, already setup to generate solutions for Visual Studio N to build with the compiler etc of Visual Studio N, to permit building with Visual Studio N-M from within the IDE.

While toolset selection should work merely by -T toolset, the issue is that this then in turn provokes a failure in cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake , claiming that the cl.exe is not able to compile a simple program. This is not the case, however, in selecting a toolset within a Visual Studio version e.g. v110_xp in Visual Studio 2012. There seems to be some complication in toolsets across Visual Studio versions, as opposed to toolsets within Visual Studio versions.

Does anyone have concrete experience of CMake in this usecase, in generating solutions for toolsets from preceding versions for use in the IDE of the current version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

That's covered by the CMake's command-line option `-T` (toolset selection), available since CMake 2.8.11. The syntax is simple:

```
cmake ... -T "the string VS uses to identify the toolset" ...
```

So, for example:

```
cmake ... -T v90 ...
```

Note that so far, this option does not have a dedicated widget in the GUI.